# R plot two timeseries on the same chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have the following data (see below) and I'd like to plot these series on the same chart.

So far I've used `ggplot`, but this gives me the `Error: mapped_discrete objects can only be created from numeric vectors`

```
 ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = data1, aes(x=timenow, y=rank, group = 1), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = data2,aes(x=timenow, y=rank, group=1) , color = "red") +
  xlab('')
```

When I annotate one of these `geom_lines` it works. any help? thanks

```
d1 <- structure(list(rank = c(1329L, 1329L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 
                                1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1319L, 1309L, 1309L, 1311L, 
                                1312L, 1299L, 1294L, 1295L, 1286L, 1281L, 1279L, 1280L, 1280L, 
                                1280L, 1280L, 1280L, 1280L, 1280L, 1280L, 1281L, 1281L, 1281L, 
                                1281L, 1280L, 1280L, 1280L, 1280L, 1280L, 1273L, 1243L, 1243L, 
                                1243L, 1243L, 1244L, 1244L, 1244L, 1242L, 1242L, 1242L, 1242L, 
                                1242L, 1242L, 1216L, 1216L, 1216L, 1216L, 1214L, 1212L, 1213L, 
                                1213L, 1213L, 1202L, 1202L, 1202L, 1203L, 1203L, 1205L, 1206L, 
                                1205L, 1205L, 1205L, 1203L, 1197L, 1190L, 1186L, 1183L, 1178L, 
                                1178L, 1179L, 1180L, 1180L, 1183L, 1177L, 1111L, 1112L, 1112L, 
                                1112L, 1110L, 1110L, 1110L, 1090L, 1070L, 1058L, 1063L, 1057L
), timenow = c("2021-03-30 23:16:40", "2021-03-30 23:19:07", 
               "2021-03-30 23:23:08", "2021-03-30 23:30:42", "2021-03-30 23:32:44", 
               "2021-03-30 23:34:39", "2021-03-30 23:36:35", "2021-03-30 23:38:52", 
               "2021-03-30 23:41:20", "2021-03-30 23:43:58", "2021-03-30 23:45:52", 
               "2021-03-30 23:57:40", "2021-03-31 00:08:48", "2021-03-31 00:16:21", 
               "2021-03-31 01:23:06", "2021-03-31 02:27:27", "2021-03-31 03:35:44", 
               "2021-03-31 04:42:04", "2021-03-31 05:53:43", "2021-03-31 07:06:10", 
               "2021-03-31 08:13:14", "2021-03-31 09:16:44", "2021-03-31 09:29:49", 
               "2021-03-31 09:30:11", "2021-03-31 09:30:33", "2021-03-31 09:30:54", 
               "2021-03-31 09:31:29", "2021-03-31 09:32:31", "2021-03-31 09:36:35", 
               "2021-03-31 10:17:51", "2021-03-31 12:34:21", "2021-03-31 12:36:11", 
               "2021-03-31 12:37:21", "2021-03-31 12:38:21", "2021-03-31 13:48:24", 
               "2021-03-31 13:50:56", "2021-03-31 13:51:18", "2021-03-31 13:52:49", 
               "2021-03-31 13:53:31", "2021-03-31 14:58:01", "2021-03-31 19:00:55", 
               "2021-03-31 19:02:18", "2021-03-31 19:04:36", "2021-03-31 19:08:42", 
               "2021-03-31 19:13:32", "2021-03-31 19:15:59", "2021-03-31 19:22:43", 
               "2021-03-31 19:24:06", "2021-03-31 19:27:18", "2021-03-31 19:32:09", 
               "2021-03-31 19:34:47", "2021-03-31 19:36:12", "2021-03-31 19:36:58", 
               "2021-03-31 22:43:55", "2021-03-31 22:44:46", "2021-03-31 22:47:27", 
               "2021-03-31 22:48:17", "2021-03-31 23:33:11", "2021-03-31 23:41:27", 
               "2021-03-31 23:42:24", "2021-03-31 23:44:54", "2021-03-31 23:46:29", 
               "2021-03-31 23:49:51", "2021-03-31 23:50:03", "2021-03-31 23:50:36", 
               "2021-03-31 23:52:03", "2021-03-31 23:55:35", "2021-04-01 00:19:41", 
               "2021-04-01 00:54:08", "2021-04-01 01:26:13", "2021-04-01 02:00:15", 
               "2021-04-01 02:33:15", "2021-04-01 03:04:53", "2021-04-01 03:38:08", 
               "2021-04-01 04:09:54", "2021-04-01 04:43:33", "2021-04-01 05:18:59", 
               "2021-04-01 05:51:32", "2021-04-01 06:23:47", "2021-04-01 06:57:48", 
               "2021-04-01 07:33:18", "2021-04-01 08:05:51", "2021-04-01 08:40:56", 
               "2021-04-01 09:13:31", "2021-04-01 20:05:42", "2021-04-01 20:07:30", 
               "2021-04-01 20:09:15", "2021-04-01 20:10:50", "2021-04-01 20:12:20", 
               "2021-04-01 20:15:19", "2021-04-01 20:16:05", "2021-04-02 01:28:56", 
               "2021-04-02 04:06:59", "2021-04-02 07:11:18", "2021-04-02 10:15:37", 
               "2021-04-02 13:20:09")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                            -96L))
d2 <- structure(list(rank = c(1128, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1116, 1114, 1114, 
                              1075, 1062, 1028, 1021, 1019, 1015, 1000, 1000, 980), timenow = structure(c(1617200553.7949, 1617200553.85089, 1617200553.86389, 1617200553.92089, 1617200608.93274, 1617207357.62103, 1617208716.32058, 1617265733.59925, 1617292862.92958, 
1617323138.14053, 1617326048.09992, 1617366509.86739, 1617380066.90475, 
1617387555.85153, 1617388066.83348, 1617393836.5841), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it worked after converting the time to the same format using `lubridate::as_datetime`

[image]